# Autodesk RCP, RCS files reading

Tags: sdk, point-clouds, autodesk, cad

I need to write a program that takes .rcp, .rcs files and pulls out points and other data from there.

I know there is a way to do this using the ReCap SDK, but this thing is available with a paid subscription. Can I use something else for this? For example, ObjectARX?